# Instagram Video Streaming per SSL/HTTPS

Tags: security, video, ssl, https, instagram

I have to integrate Instagram Videos on a webpage which is completely SSL Secure. Therefore i need Instagram Video in streaming in https. i tried it as following.

step 1: Get basic information regading video and mp4 URL

https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagram.com/p/lm3myhH9Cm/

i get following link in returing JSON.
http://distilleryvesper9-9.ak.instagram.com/852b996aad1811e385fa0aedbb89c471_101.mp4

i replaced http through https and embedd the URL in HTML video player as following.

step 2: play video in browser

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>  
     <source src="https://distilleryvesper9-9.ak.instagram.com/852b996aad1811e385fa0aedbb89c471_101.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
</video>
```

After i call page in browser it show me security issue regarding certificate. is there any way to solve this issue?

or Instagram provide any way to embed there contents in SSL secure websites, through HTTPS.

i will be very happy for any further guidance.

Thnaks in advance